# How to reach SendBird logs?

Tags: react-native, sendbird

I am using sendbird.com to include messaging services in my application. 
I am implementing push notifications in the app using SendBird dashboard. I have followed the SendBird documentation to implement push notifications in iOS but I still don't receive any notifications on my device.

I want to access the SendBird logs(like Parse logs), so that I can understand what is the error SendBird is facing in sending me Push Notifications.

Does anyone know how to access the logs?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We're working on push notification logs and should be available soon.

Before the feature arrives, you can take a look at this FAQ to debug the issue.

https://help.sendbird.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002331048-Why-am-I-not-receiving-push-notifications-

Thanks!